# How to fix Unrecognized field "schemaLocation" when demarshalling a XML file

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I run into this error when deserializing a XML message:

> Unrecognized field "schemaLocation" (class com.example.RefreshTokenType), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "authorized_party", "audience", "meta", "client_id"]).

```
<p:RefreshToken authorized_party="" client_id="15d8b31f4823aeaf21d3ba6ee87a4557"
    xmlns:p="http://example.com/xsd/oauth/v2/oauth-spec.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/xsd/oauth/v2/oauth-spec.xsd oauth-v2-spec.xsd ">
    <p:meta id="meta111" locale="*" name="x" value="x" />
</p:RefreshToken>
```

The background is I am switching from *org.eclipse.persistence.moxy* to *FasterXML/Jackson* for marshalling both JSON and XML with Jersey. Everything works fine until I get the XML message including **schemaLocation**.

Here is my deserialization setting:

```
public static void enableDeserializationSetting(ObjectMapper reader) {
  Set<Class<?>> jaxbClasses = collectJaxbAnnotatedClasses();
  reader.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
  reader.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
  reader.registerSubtypes(jaxbClasses);
}
```

and this is the snippet from my http://example.com/xsd/oauth/v2/oauth-spec.xsd:

```
    <xs:element name="RefreshToken" type="RefreshTokenType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="RefreshTokenType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="meta" type="MetaDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="audience" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element> <!-- mandated by OpenID Connect spec (aud) -->
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="authorized_party" type="xs:string" use="optional" /> 
        <xs:attribute name="client_id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

Could someone shed a light on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable the [`FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) feature in your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) setting [`ignoreUnknown`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()) to `true`:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RefreshTokenType {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, I guess you mean to say *disable* for FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, right?

Comment: @pirent Yes, disable :)

Comment: Ciao, I think the real problem is somewhere else. Because when I disable that property, it still didn't work for me. But when I did debug on DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty, it does check whether that property is disable. So your answer should help, but i may misconfigure it somewhere so that the configuration doesn't take any effect. But many thanks.